# How to find the next highest value in a new column? (SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with multiple work orders for the same product with each row showing a different hour meter for how long the product has been run. I would like to create a new column that shows the next highest hour meter reading for the product next to the highest one but have not had much luck. I've been trying to rank the entries by hour meter but have not had any luck past that

```
("ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Product ORDER BY Current_Counter_Reading DESC") 'Ranking'
```

Does anyone have any advice on how to approach this? Below is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
Product | Work Order | Hour Meter
--------+------------+------------
Car1       1            100
Car1       2            200

Product | Higher Hour Meter | Lower Hour Meter
--------+-------------------+-----------------
Car1          200                 100
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can also select the top 2 and use min/max for this - be careful of the assumption about the diversity (or singularity) of values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See also `LEAD` or `LAG` window functions:

```
WITH cte1 AS (
      SELECT t.*
           , LEAD(HourMeter) OVER (PARTITION BY Product ORDER BY HourMeter DESC) AS NextLower
           , ROW_NUMBER()    OVER (PARTITION BY Product ORDER BY HourMeter DESC) AS rn
        FROM work_orders AS t
     )
SELECT Product, HourMeter, NextLower
  FROM cte1
 WHERE rn = 1
 ORDER BY Product
;
```

Given the following data:

```
+-----------+---------+-----------+
| WorkOrder | Product | HourMeter |
+-----------+---------+-----------+
|         2 | Car1    |       200 |
|         1 | Car1    |       100 |
|         3 | Car1    |        50 |
|         5 | Car2    |        66 |
|         4 | Car2    |        55 |
|         6 | Car2    |        45 |
+-----------+---------+-----------+
```

The result:

```
+---------+-----------+-----------+
| Product | HourMeter | NextLower |
+---------+-----------+-----------+
| Car1    |       200 |       100 |
| Car2    |        66 |        55 |
+---------+-----------+-----------+
```

[Working Test Case](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ef6ba974acae72dd7dc2d13fd5cbe040)

Comment: @rupp2d2 If you're sure this is the best acceptable answer for you, don't forget to "accept" the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming lower meter is the 2nd highest

Here we use the window function `row_number() over()` in concert with a conditional aggregation.

```
Select Product
      ,Higher_Meter   = max( case when RN=1 then [Hour Meter] end)
      ,Lower_Meter    = max( case when RN=2 then [Hour Meter] end)
 From (
        Select * 
              ,RN = row_number() over (partition by Product order by [Hour Meter] desc)
          From YourTable
      ) src
 Group By Product
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT 'Car1' as Product,1 as WorkOrder,100 as HourMeter
union all
select 'Car1',2,200
union all
select 'Car1',3,20
)
SELECT 
   c1.Product,
   MAX(c1.HourMeter) as HigherHourMeter,
   MAX(c2.HourMeter) LowerHourMeter
FROM CTE c1
INNER JOIN CTE c2 ON c2.Product=c1.Product and c2.HourMeter<c1.HourMeter
GROUP BY c1.Product;
```